# Изменение шрифта текста в label в зависимости от объёма (размера) текста

Tags: c#, winforms

У нас есть label к примеру размером 241;156. И нам надо, чтобы весь текст поместился на всём label.

Comment: _Простите, не нам, а вам._ (c)  [TextRenderer.MeasureText](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext?view=netframework-4.7.2), [Graphics.MeasureString](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите уменьшить шрифт текста для этого (если текст не помещается):

```
Float maxSize = 24.0f;
label1.Text = "Ваш текст";
label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.FontFamily, maxSize, label1.Font.Style);
while(label1.Width < System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText(label1.Text, 
 new Font(label1.Font.FontFamily, label1.Font.Size, label1.Font.Style)).Width)
{
    label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.FontFamily, label1.Font.Size - 0.5f, label1.Font.Style);
}
```

Comment: Желательно освобождать ресурсы: диспозить ранее созданный шрифт. Или, как вариант, закэшировать шрифты и использовать повторно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Прошу прощения, а разве он не будет очищен, когда на него перестанет ссылаться существующий объект? Мы же работаем с управляемыми ресурсами?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я правильно понимаю, что когда хэндлы закончатся, сборщик все равно сработает?

Comment: Сборка мусора недетерминированна и произойдет она неизвестно когда (а может и вообще никогда не произойти, если памяти хватает). Нужно понимать, что ресурсы есть разные. Например, _хендлы_ операционной системы. На каждый шрифт нужен один хендл. Между тем количество хендлов ограничено (по-моему, десять тысяч на процесс). В итоге хендлов может не хватать на все нужды процесса.

Comment: GC следит только за памятью. О хендлах он ничего не знает.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Все в порядке )

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я провел эксперимент. Вставил код выше в цикл с 10 млн. итераций. Через несколько 1,5 минуты выполнение завершилось, 9 раз запускался сборщик мусора (видно в VS), потребление памяти все время 23 Мб.

Comment: А что если наоборот, хочешь увеличить размер шрифта? просто текст может быть как большим, так и мелким, и если он мелкий, чтобы на весь label распространился

Comment: @Даниил Просто установите максимальный размер шрифта по умолчанию (например 24) и он уменьшится до нужного размера. Я дополнил пример.